# Flutter push route for Taskmanager?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, taskmanager

Since in my case it is about an insurance app, I have implemented a local app lock. When opening the app from the task manager a new screen is pushed and the fingerprint is requested.

My problem now is that Android and iOS always show a **screenshot of the app in the taskmanager** and therefore maybe also relevant data.

Here I would like to show an own screen, e.g. the app logo in the middle of the screen. Since I can't find anything about this while researching, I tried to push a screen while pausing (AppLifecycleState.paused). This screen is either not pushed in time or the approach is completely wrong.

```
if(state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
    navigatorKey.currentState.push(CustomRoute(builder: (ctx) => LockScreen(),));
 }
```

Is there an official way to do this in Flutter or has anyone with experience already done something like this in Flutter?

Comment: For iOS https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1838/_index.html

Comment: There are native options for both Android and iOS. Of course they can also be accessed in Flutter. But I'm explicitly looking for a way to do this directly in Flutter, without using native code, especially in view of the future and more systems and flutter web i want to avoid native code where possible.. Thanks for the link anyway. If anyone search for native Android, this is possible via `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE`.